# How to add few lines before a keyword in VIM using Shell Script

Tags: linux, shell, vim

I have a file like this,

```
 xyz:\
  :admin.auth=y:\
  :cmd.stopndm=y:\
  :pstmt.copy.ulimit=y:\
  :pstmt.upload=y:\
```

How do I find for xyz and add few lines before that line. So that the file looks like this,

```
abc@1234:\
 :admin.id=XXX:\
 :descrip=XXX:

xyz:\
 :admin.auth=y:\
 :cmd.stopndm=y:\
 :pstmt.copy.ulimit=y:\
```

This should be updated using shell script. Can anyone help me here?

Comment: `... in vim using shell script` what do you mean by that?

Comment: in vim, you just search `/xyz:`, then press `O`, now start your typing work...

Comment: Hi Kent, What I meant was to do all this in a shell script. I have to open the file using script and search for xyz and add the lines.

Comment: shell script can update files, why do you need open the file with vim?

Answer (score 2):

I would use [ed](/questions/tagged/ed), not vim

```
$ cat file
xyz:\
 :admin.auth=y:\
 :cmd.stopndm=y:\
 :pstmt.copy.ulimit=y:\
 :pstmt.upload=y:\
```

```
$ ed file <<'END_ED'
/xyz
i
abc@1234:\
 :admin.id=XXX:\
 :descrip=XXX:

.
w
q
END_ED
```

```
$ cat file
abc@1234:\
 :admin.id=XXX:\
 :descrip=XXX:

xyz:\
 :admin.auth=y:\
 :cmd.stopndm=y:\
 :pstmt.copy.ulimit=y:\
 :pstmt.upload=y:\
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Vim for this simple editing task. Though it can be used for automation, I would only use this if I absolutely needed a plugin or custom Vimscript to do the editing task. For scripting, there are simpler tools.

Here's a solution using [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

```
$ cat > file <<'EOF'
xyz:\
 :admin.auth=y:\
 :cmd.stopndm=y:\
 :pstmt.copy.ulimit=y:\
 :pstmt.upload=y:\
EOF
```

```
$ sed -i -e '/xyz:/i\
abc@1234:\\\
 :admin.id=XXX:\\\
 :descrip=XXX:\

' file
```

```
$ cat file
abc@1234:\
 :admin.id=XXX:\
 :descrip=XXX:

xyz:\
 :admin.auth=y:\
 :cmd.stopndm=y:\
 :pstmt.copy.ulimit=y:\
 :pstmt.upload=y:\
```

It searches (`/xyz:/`) for the line before which the contents should be inserted, and then first inserts the text via the `i` command (backslashes must be doubled, and newlines must end with one).